# Recommend service to authenticate service communication in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, web-services, authentication, authorization, amazon-cognito

We are building a service on AWS which should be usable to subscribed business users. The goal would be to have a user register and return an access token which can be used until revoked (similar to gitlab). This token is then integrated into a service of the user to communicate with our services.

As we come from an AWS background we investigated cognito first. However cognito seems to be more oriented towards endusers rather than business users.
It only allows (kinda) unlimited refresh tokens. But with refresh tokens the user still has to request new access tokens every hour which is cumbersome in service to service communication.

So our questions are:

1. Is this a recommended workflow? (business user registers -> receives unlimited access token until manually revoked -> integrates into users service)
2. Are there any services on AWS that provide such access tokens? Should we implement such a thing ourselves?

The goal is to have the user implement as little as possible in his own service while still providing sufficient security.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your service can be accessed using APIs you can use the API gateway to provide your business customers with a [key](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-api-usage-plans.html) that they have to use to access your API. You can use this API to trigger lambda or on EC2 which will then access your service.

If you don't want to use APIs, you can always use a cognito identity pools with sdk. There are libraries in Javascript and Android which will automatically handle the token refreshing bit.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes we plan to use an API as communication. I forgot to mention that the token would need to be associated with the user as he can access his own data on our service (to prevent that he can access other users data). Is this possible with API keys? Or would the lambda which is triggered be responsible for this?

Comment: API keys are unique for each user. You can use them with usage plans and lambda authorizers to control access to your api. See more here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-api-usage-plans.html